# JavaSwing coordination on JPanel issue?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jpanel, java-2d

I use netbeans IDE to create Gui then I customize the Jpanel2 and draw polygon on it this is code snippet

> int[] polygonXs = { 151, 153, 158, 159, 154};
>      int[] polygonYs = { 6, 1, 3, 8, 10};
>      Shape shape = new Polygon(polygonXs, polygonYs, polygonXs.length);

Then the problem is  the point(151,6) (153,1) (158,3) (159,8) (154,10) is in JFrame coordinates.
 In additional now (0,0) is at the top left of the JFrame but I want (0,0) be at the top left of Jpanel2(black background). So how to fix that (code of Jpanel2 below the image).

[image: This is jPanel2 class]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class J2d1 extends JPanel{
public static final String TITLE = "Affine Transform Demo";

int[] polygonXs = { 151, 153, 158, 159, 154};
int[] polygonYs = { 6, 1, 3, 8, 10};
Shape shape = new Polygon(polygonXs, polygonYs, polygonXs.length);
double x = 50.0, y = 50.0;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

    AffineTransform saveTransform = g2d.getTransform();
    AffineTransform identity = new AffineTransform();
    g2d.setTransform(identity);

    g2d.setColor(Color.green);
    g2d.fill(shape);
    g2d.translate(x, y);
    g2d.scale(2.2, 2.2);
    g2d.fill(shape);

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
        g2d.translate(50.0, 5.0);
        g2d.setColor(Color.blue);
        g2d.fill(shape);
        g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(15.0));
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2d.fill(shape);            
    }
    g2d.setTransform(saveTransform);

    } 
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) Use a combination of `AffineTransform` instances to change the co-ordinate system.

Comment: BTW - it looks like you've already started experimenting with `AffineTransform` instances, but the code above would have exactly the same effect as if you hadn't..

Comment: A side note (also @AndrewThompson ) : One should **never** call `g2d.setTransform(...)` with an affine transform that was created manually (not even with the identity transform). See the JavaDoc of this method for details: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#setTransform-java.awt.geom.AffineTransform-

Comment: Thank you.So how could I use the coordinates of Jpanel2 instead of jFrame as a question

Answer (score 1):

Use SwingUtilities class. It has the methods

```
public static Point convertPoint(Component source,Point aPoint,Component destination)
public static Point convertPoint(Component source,int x, int y,Component destination)
```

where you can pass coordinates and convert from one component's coordinates to another componnet's coordinates.

Comment: Do you have an example I don't understand as code above I just want to change JFrame's coordinates to JPanel2's coordinates.